# ASP.NET MVC Dropdown List not selecting

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am trying to create a dropdownlist for an ASP.NET MVC Application. For some reason, the option I select for my dropdownlist does not get selected when it is passed to the controller. What I want to do is send the form as an email, so I need to retrieve all the information the user will select. When I run the program with a breakpoint inside the `BuyingForm` function, the debugger is telling me that the model that is being passed into `BuyingForm` contains the variable `propertyType` with the correct options, just it says that the `Selected` property is false for all options.

BuyingControler.cs

```
using program.Models;

namespace program.Controllers
{
    public class BuyingController : Controller
    {
        private BuyingModel buyingModel = new BuyingModel();
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            return View(buyingModel);
        }
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult BuyingForm(string returnUrl, BuyingModel model)
    {
        //SendMail()

        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Buying");
    }
}
```

BuyingModel.cs

```
namespace program.Models
{
    public class BuyingModel
    {

    //[Display(Name = "What type of property are you looking for?")]
    //[Required(ErrorMessage = "You must select the type of property you are looking for")]
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> propertyType
    {
        get
        {
            return new[]
            {
                new SelectListItem {Value = "1", Text = "Any" },
                new SelectListItem {Value = "2", Text = "Single Family Home" },
                new SelectListItem {Value = "3", Text = "Condo"}
            };
        }
    }
}
```

Index.cshtml

```
@{
    @model program.Models.BuyingModel;
}

  <div class="col-6 rightScroll">
        <h2>Property Basics</h2>
        @using (Html.BeginForm("BuyingForm", "Buying", FormMethod.Post))
        {
            @Html.LabelFor(Model => Model.propertyType, new { @class = "testing" })
            @Html.DropDownListFor(Model => Model.propertyType,
                                  new SelectList(Model.propertyType, "Value", "Text"))

            <button type="submit">Send</button>
        }
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please modify your model based on below code:-

```
public class BuyingModel
    {
        public string SelectedPropertyId { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> propertyType
        {
            get
            {
                return new[]
                {
                new SelectListItem {Value = "1", Text = "Any" },
                new SelectListItem {Value = "2", Text = "Single Family Home" },
                new SelectListItem {Value = "3", Text = "Condo"}
            };
            }
        }
    }
```

I have introduced a SelectedPropertyId field to store the selected property type from UI.
Please populate the SelectedPropertyId field while posting back the form.
On the view please render the dropdown like below :-

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedPropertyId, Model.propertyType)
```

Above code should hopefully fix your issue.

Comment: Sorry correction ,The field SelectedPropertyId should be auto populated from UI while posting back the form.You will be getting the Id you will have to parse the result from select list item property to get the name.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. For some reason I have not been able to find an example of strictly using model for dropdownlist, but I knew I was close! Appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your HttpPost form handler `BuyingForm`

What i changed and after that it worked

Created new model:

```
/// <summary>
/// Model for request from user form
/// </summary>
public class BuingRequest 
{
    public string PropertyType { get; set; }
}
```

Changed handler post form:

```
public class BuyingController : Controller
    {
        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult BuyingForm(string returnUrl, BuingRequest model)
        {
            //SendMail()
            //Response.Write(model.PropertyType);

            return new ContentResult() { Content = model.PropertyType };
        }
    }
```

In your example you don't need use the same model that and view.